# parsing user string, escape characters

Tags: c++, string, escaping

How can I parse a string and replace all occurences of a `\.` with something? Yet at the same time replace all `\\` with `\` (literal).. Examples:

`hello \. world` => `hello "." world`
`hello \\. world`=> `hello  \. world`
`hello \\\. world` => `hello \"." world`

The first reaction was to use std::replace_if, as in the following:

```
    bool escape(false);
    std::replace_if(str.begin(), str.end(), [&] (char c) {
        if (c == '\\') {
            escape = !escape;
        } else if (escape && c == '.') {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    },"\".\"");
```

However that simply changes `\.` by `\"."` sequences. Also it won't be working for `\\` parts in the staring.

Is there an elegant approach to this? Before I start doing a hack job with a for loop & rebuilding the string?

Comment: You should be replacing strings, e.g. `"\\\\" -> "\\"`, `"\\x" -> "x"`; not chars.

Comment: I think *"a hack job with a for loop & rebuilding the string"* would be the least ugly solution.

Answer (score 2):

Elegant approach: a finite state machine with three states:

- looking for '\' (iterating through string)
- found '\' and next character is '.'
- found '\' and next character is '\'

To implement you could use the iterators in the default string library and the `replace` method.

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/replace/

Comment: uhm HOW would I use the replace method then? Especially since if you remove elements from a container the iterators get invalidated..

Comment: You could start a new iterator from where the pattern was found on the last string plus the size of the string you inserted.
Actually, I think it would more obvious just use the string's `operator[]`, with an integer index.

Comment: I think it'd be simpler not to use `string.replace` but to build a new string from the original, character by character.  Regardless, an FSM is definitely the way to go here.